# difference in value of uint16_t with printf

Tags: c, gcc, printf, scanf

The output of below program is confusing.

```
uint16_t        first = 10, second = 20, third = 30;
// printf("%p\n", &first);
scanf("%d", &second);       // "%d" used intentionally.
printf("%" SCNu16 " ", first);
printf("%" SCNu16 " ", second);
printf("%" SCNu16 "\n", third);
```

With first `printf` commented I get `10 20 0`. (The `"%d"` in `scanf` might be causing this. It works fine if I use `"%" SCNu16` in place of `%d`).

With first `printf` uncommented I get `0 20 30`.
Confusion is - why is `printf` causing the difference in output? This is a consistent behavior.

Comment: what is `*uint16_t  `?

Comment: What is `SCNu16`? In C use `PRIu16`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin `PRI_` macros are for the `fprintf` family, while `SCN_` are for `fscanf` functions.

Comment: You should use `scanf("%" SCNu16, &second);`.

Comment: You should specify what input you are giving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code,

```
 scanf("%d", &second);
```

is undefined behavior. `%d` expects the argument to be a pointer to a signed integer type (`int`).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2, *`fscanf` function*

> [...] Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a `*`, the
>   result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following
>   the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. If this object
>   does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented
>   in the object, the behavior is undefined.

That said, `SCNu`*`N`* macro is for `fscanf` family, `fprintf()` family has the counterpart as `PRIu`*`N`*.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a "consistent behavior" or not depends on your definition of it. I get the same behavior when I run your code, but it does not change the fact that you have *undefined behavior* in your program.

I tried compiling it with `-O3` and then I got the output `10 20 30` when giving the input `20`, both with and without the said `printf` statement.

So while it could be fun to speculate about why your code behaves the way it does, it is not very meaningful. The code is invalid, so you have no guarantees.

I also tried switching the order of variable declaration: `uint16_t third=30, second=20, first=10;` The behavior changed, although it should not if the code were valid.

Comment: A reasonable optimizer sees that first and third are not changed before the printf and the printf gets optimized to a simple puts. The variable itself it optimized away so nothing for scanf to corrupt by using %d on an uint16_t.